# Backup and restore don't work for me in Oracle

Tags: oracle11g

i try this for backup:

```
$ exp scott/tiger FULL=y FILE='d:\demo.dmp';
```

and this for restore:

```
$ imp scott/tiger FULL=y FILE='d:\demo.dmp';
```

and after restore i can't see the data in my tables.

(i work on Oracle 11.2.0 64bit)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Gali-

Check this out.  It's tailored for 10g, but the commands should remain the same.

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/OracleDataPump10g.php

Pay special attention to the "Getting Started" section where it talks about creating a directory, as well as the section dubbed "Database Exports/Imports."  Hope this helps.

-CJ